# Build methods with async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I know I can use async or bluebird but really do not know how

I have the follow

```
function Builder()
{
}

Builder.prototype.heavyProcess ...
Builder.prototype.ioProcessAfterHeavyProcess ...
Builder.prototype.afterHeavyProcessTwo ...
Builder.prototype.afterIoProcess ...
```

for the `Builder.heavyProcess` i do in sync way (I think so) for the `ioProcessAfterHeavyProcess` i'm using async.waterfall

```
function ioProcessAfterHeavyProcess(cb) {
 async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {            
            heavyProcess(...);
            callback(...);
        },
        function(callback) {
            callback(...);   
        }
    ], cb);
}
```

but i dont know how to do with afterIoProcess

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your async implementation looks okay. Are you wondering how to call afterIoProcess as a part of this flow? Or does afterIoProcess do something different that you don't know how to async-ify?

Comment: I had a few mistakes that I did not understand well at first, but after analyze it well, the code I stay clear and functional